# How to combine these animations in CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I need help with making exactly the same animation as this one in CSS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/saA3w.jpg

So far I have made this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 1.9s;
  left: 0%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 0, 0% 100%, 0 100%);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.6, 0, 1, 1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  right: 15%;
  animation-name: move_image;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/isvINjD.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  animation-name: showup;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes move {
  60% {
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes move_image {
  100% {
    right: -15%;
  }
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Animation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay_image"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I can't make the last part which is the one to the left to appear correctly as shown in video:

[image: Image of a problematic part]

When I try, the last animation gets stuck inside this dark gray slider to the right instead of appearing after it and staying on the screen at the end. :/

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the code like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay_image {
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 0) right/100% 100%,
    url("https://i.imgur.com/isvINjD.png") center/auto 80vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation:move 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes move{
  0% {
    width:0;
    background-size:100% 100%,auto 80vh;
  }
  50% {
    width:100%;
    background-size:100% 100%,auto 80vh;
  }
  100% {
    width:100%;
    background-size:0% 100%,auto 80vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay_image"></div>
```

Also like below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay_image {
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  width:0;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/isvINjD.png") center/auto 80vh no-repeat;
  animation:move 2s forwards;
}

.overlay_image:before {
  content:"";
  flex:1;
  margin-left:auto;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0 0) 0 0/100% 100%,
    url("https://i.imgur.com/isvINjD.png") center/auto 80vh
    #fff;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation:fade 1s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes move{
  50%,100% {
    width:100%;
  }
}
@keyframes fade{
  100% {
    flex:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay_image"></div>
```